# Can I find mysql version from data files, need for data restoration

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, data-recovery

I have a very odd situation going on here. I had a linux box running ubuntu 8.10 and MySQL server with a Wordpress installation on it hosting an internal blog for our company. The machine that this was running on has crapped out, but I was able to put the drive into an enclosure and gain access to the files and recover the MySQL data folder.

We are mostly a Windows company and I have very limited linux experience. Before this machine crashed we were experimenting with moving this blog to a Windows Virtual Machine running PHP for IIS; and we have an older copy of the Wordpress database up and running on MySQL 5.1.

I am currently trying to retrieve the latest data from the linux MySQL data folder and import it into the current database but I am having problems.

Problems so far:

1. I do not know what version of MySQL was installed on the linux box
2. I see `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`, and `ibdata1` on the linux MySQL data folder, but am not sure if it was truly running InnoDB or not as I also have `.frm`, `.myd`, and `.myi` files in the wordpress folder

If I can figure out the version of the linux box MySQL I might be able to create a virtual machine to run linux and MySQL so I can copy the data folder and then do an export dump; unless someone else knows of an easier way to get the data into my current database.

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Nathan

Answer (score 7):

Look for "mysql_upgrade_info" file.

Comment: Ok, I have this file. How should I open it or is there something else I need to do to it?

Comment: Opened file in Notepad++ and found the version number. Thank you for helping me with this issue.